# How to use sensors rotation matrix in min3d to rotate parsed object

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-sensors, rotational-matrices, min3d

I want to rotate objects parsed from .obj file in min3d. 
I need to use a rotation matrix got from sensors. I know how to do this in pure OpenGL but I can't figure out what to use (min3d.core.Renderer probably?) and how in min3d.
I like min3d and it parses .obj files very nicely so I don't really want to abandon it and use pure openGL. 
I know i can use the rotate() method but it uses Eulers angles and i need to use rotation matrix.
Here's the code:

```
public class HurleyLoading extends RendererActivity implements SensorEventListener{

private Object3dContainer hurleyModel;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor sensorAcc;
private Sensor sensorMagnetic;

 private float[] accelData = new float[3];
 private float[] magnetData = new float[3];

private final float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
float[] orientation = new float[3];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAcc = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorMagnetic =  sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorAcc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorMagnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorAcc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorMagnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    //this.onResume();
}
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void initScene() {

    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());
    scene.lights().add(new Light());

    IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ,
            getResources(), "ie.tyndall.hurleyopengl:raw/hurley_obj", true);
    parser.parse();

    hurleyModel = parser.getParsedObject();
    hurleyModel.scale().x = hurleyModel.scale().y =  hurleyModel.scale().z = 1.4f;
    hurleyModel.position().y = -1.8f;
    hurleyModel.position().x = .4f;

    scene.addChild(hurleyModel);        
}
@Override
public void updateScene() {
    /**some rotation code can go here but rotation() method has to use 
     * eulers angles (X/Y/Z euler rotation of object, using Euler angles. 
     * Units should be in degrees, to match OpenGL usage)which is no use for me
     * as i need to use rotation matrix
     **/        
}

//@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      loadSensorData(event);
      SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelData,
                 magnetData);
}
private void loadSensorData(SensorEvent event) {
      final int type = event.sensor.getType();
      if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
       accelData = event.values.clone();
      }
      if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
       magnetData = event.values.clone();
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to calculate angle from your rotation matrix and set it in updateScene() like this:
    obj.rotation().x = ?
    obj.rotation().y = ?
    obj.rotation().z = ?